# Do movement bonuses from different sources stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, stacking

Do fast movement bonus from the Monk and Bloodrager stack with the elemental movement bloodline power bonus of the Sorcerer?

Answer (score 4):

## Your examples all stack, but not all speed bonuses will

When it comes to stacking of bonuses for anything in Pathfinder, it depends on the type of the [bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/#Bonus). For the majority of bonus types, multiple bonuses of the same type do not stack. There are a handful of specific bonus types that *do* stack (Circumstance, Dodge), but it is basically not currently possible to receive a speed bonus of those types. If a bonus is of an unspecified type, it always stacks with all other bonuses.

The land speed bonus granted by a Monk is explicitly an Enhancement bonus, and so won't stack with any other Enhancement bonuses to speed. For instance, the spell [Carrying Wind](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/carrying-wind/) provides varying Enhancement bonuses to speed, none of which would stack with the Monk fast movement. Haste, another common speed bonus, is also an enhancement bonus.

The speed bonus provided by the Fire [Elemental sorcerer Bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/elemental-bloodline/) does not mention any type for the bonus, meaning it is untyped, and so stacks with any other speed bonuses. All of the other movement types provided by the bloodline are not land speeds, and are at fixed rates.

The [Bloodrager](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/) Fast Movement ability explicitly states that it stacks with all other land speed bonuses.